# How kubernetes makes 'weird' IP addresses accessible?

Tags: kubernetes

How does it work actually? When I start my Kubernetes cluster I can access the address `0.0.0.0` in my browser. When I create a LoadBalancer I can access some other address in my browser e.g. `174.23.0.12`. How does Kubernetes know that those addresses are not colliding with some other addresses? Is it possible to e.g. serve a react app on some IP like that?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, 0.0.0.0 is a non-standard broadcast address (according to [RFC 1122, section 3.3.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122#page-66)) so your request to 0.0.0.0 is received by all hosts on your local network and the address is *not* routed, so it stays in your local network. You as client don't need to know the actual target address.

Comment: What about different addresses? Like `174.23.0.12`? How can I let's say create a virtual machine on my PC that I can access with that IP and ssh to it?